# Elasticsearch - Simple Query String not returning result: Multiple Fields with Boost Values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a simple_query_string query with multiple fields, each field has different boost values. However, if there is a match of a query in any of the fields with less or no boost value the query returns no result. Is it a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

**The phrase 'Peace for Change' is there in the title field only but the query returns no result.**

Here's my query:

````
{ 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "Peace for Change",
            "default_operator": "AND",
            "flags": "PREFIX|PHRASE|NOT|AND|OR|FUZZY|WHITESPACE",
            "fields": [
              "*",
              "systemNumber^5",
              "global_search",
              "objectType^2",
              "partTypes.text",
              "partTypes.id",
              "people^2",
              "person^2",
              "org^2",
              "title^2",
              "Location.displayName",
              "briefDescription",
              "physicalDescription",
              "summaryDescription",
              "flatPersonsNameId",
              "flatPeoplesNameId",
              "flatOrganisationsNameId",
              "primaryDate",
              "primaryDateEarliest",
              "primaryDateLatest"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: is there any analyzer in the title field? Could you provide the document with text Peace for Change?

Comment: Yes, there is a standard analyzer with the title field.  Sorry I can't provide you with the exact document but here's a similar document https://api.vam.ac.uk/v2/museumobject/O696516 
If I search for the title with the same query, it doesn't return results, although the phrase is the exact title, however it isn't there in any of the other fields.

Comment: I did a example with your query and get the results. POST idx_test/_doc
{
  "title":"Peace for Change"
}
And I used your query.

Comment: Mine isn't working.